# Melhor maneira de manter dados que dependem de uma condição

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Hipoteticamente tenho uma tabela `publicação` que possui, por padrão, os atributos `autores` (deriva de uma tabela de relacionamento),`titulo`, `edição`, `editora` e `ano`. Porém, dependendo do tipo de publicação (como `livro`, `artigo em periódico`, `artigo em jornal` e outros) haveria necessidade de coletar dados adicionais.

Por exemplo, se a `publicação` for do tipo `livro` haveria necessidade de armazenar `quantidade de páginas` e `volume`. Porém, uma `publicação` pode ser genérica e não possuir um tipo.

Minha dúvida é: qual a melhor maneira de tratar essa situação?

Eu pensei em duas formas possíveis:

1. - Criar uma tabela `publicação` com os atributos padrão.
   - Adicionar em `publicação` uma coluna `tipo`
   - Criar uma tabela para cada tipo possível de publicação com seus atributos particulares
   - Relacionar essas novas tabelas à `publicação` e formar uma chave composta

ou

2. - Criar uma tabela `publicação` e adicionar todos os atributos possíveis dos tipos e fazer o tratamento na aplicação server-side.
     (isso não me parece uma boa solução)

Tenho pouca experiência em banco de dados. Acredito que hajam outras soluções. Gostaria de saber quais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existem soluções absolutamente certas em desenvolvimento de software. Então a melhor maneira depende de muita coisa.

O que dá para dizer que o a forma considerada mais correta é a primeira por envolver a [normalização do dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Mais correta não significa a melhor. Há situações que você deve fazer o que não é tão correto assim para atingir o melhor resultado para a situação específica.

Em geral quanto menos informações "opcionais" você tiver, melhor, mas sempre pode haver motivos para fazer isto, eventualmente até por otimização.

Mesmo definir o que é melhor já é complicado. Melhor em que? Para que? Para quem? Quando? Mesmo que atenda um critério, não conseguirá atender outros.

Alternativas existem. Por exemplo você pode ir mais fundo na normalização, ir até a [6a. forma normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) ou a [forma de pares de chave e valor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/key_normal_form). Não recomendo mas é uma forma de desacoplar os dados.

A segunda forma só deveria ser adotada se você tiver problemas reais de performance (se for medido corretamente), o que eu duvido que seja o caso.

Minha única dúvida é sobre a utilização da chave composta. A não ser que tenha algo que você não informou eu acho que não precisa. O `id` da publicação pode ser utilizado como chave primária na tabela de cada tipo específico.

Se a publicação for genérica, basta deixar a coluna que indica o tipo sem valor, provavelmente como nulo.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Realmente, utilizar o `id` da publicação como chave primária nas tabelas de tipos parece uma boa alternativa para essa situação!

Answer (score 2):

Se fores para a segunda alternativa a tabela publicação não vai escalar (ou seja se tiveres muitos registos a performance para obteres informação específica vai ser má). Para além disso tens esse "tratamento de informação" na aplicação o que eventualmente também se pode tornar numa dor de cabeça. Não, não é uma boa solução.

A primeira alternativa é a melhor e na verdade estás a falar de um passo comum na construção de bases de dados, a Segunda Forma Normal ou 2FN. A normalização de dados é um conjunto de procedimentos que se seguem para obter um armazenamento consistente e um acesso eficaz à informação. Tens muita informação na net, a começar pela [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados), com tudo bem explicado e exemplos. Será bom perceberes estes princípios para depois realizares da melhor forma o teu modelo de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a primeira forma seria a melhor, inclusive pensando em escalabilidade e futuras implementações que possa a vir necessitar.
Além disso não "incha" a tabela, resultando em uma performance otimizada.

Para os casos em que você precise juntar tudo, você pode criar uma View no banco de dados que retorna as informações agrupadas.

A primeira forma também corresponde ao padrão de normalização de banco de dados, a Segunda Forma Normal, conforme já mencionado pelo ***Craveiro***.

Mais tarde ao ser necessário acrescentar outras características de um tipo não previsto hoje: Publicação online, post no facebook, por exemplo, você vai ter uma maneira muito mais fácil de fazer isso, basta acrescentar mais um tipo e ajustar a View.

Ou seja, a primeira opção vai tornar a tua vida bem mais fácil no futuro.

Comment: É isso aí! Outra dúvida que tenho é: posso utilizar algum prefixo para identificar visualmente as *tabelas dos tipos*? ex: `pub_livro`, `pub_artigo` e etc. Existe alguma convenção para esse caso?

Comment: Pode sim, sem problemas. Geralmente o prefixo da tabela é uma escolha do próprio desenvolvedor, mas a convenção é usar 2 ou 3 letras e o underline, exatamente como você colocou "pub_<nome da tabela>".