# Modelar tabela "Produto" para múltiplos tipos de produtos diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, modelo-relacional

Como modelar a Tabela **Produto** de um banco de dados? Esta tabela deverá armazenar as seguintes informações: id, nome do produto, quantidade, preço, status (se ela esta em estoque, se vai ser devolvida) e informações pertinentes a cada tipo de produto: alimentícios (natural e industrializados), artigos de vestuário, cama/mesa/banho, relógios (e adereços como pulseiras e colares), artigos de perfumaria, eletroeletrônicos e eletrodomésticos e móveis.

Esta tabela deve permitir filtrar por características de cada produto, cada característica é pertinente a um tipo de produto, logo eu deveria ser capaz de filtrar móveis por tipo de madeira e computadores por quantidade de memória RAM, porém ambas as características pertencem a um único tipo de produto.

SQL que já fiz:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000),
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);
```

*Ela esta seguindo convenções de nomenclatura do CakePHP.

**OBS:** O SGBD é MySQL ultima versão.

**EDIT:**

Seguinte orientações obtidas através da pergunta: [Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74127/melhor-maneira-de-manter-dados-que-dependem-de-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) posso separar 8 tipos de produtos e separar as características para cada tipo, porém como irei estruturar isso na forma de Entidade Relacionamento? *Exibe poucos tipos porque me informaram que a pergunta estava grande.

**Tipos:**

- Bebidas

  - Tipo da bebida
  - Conteúdo da embalagem
  - Fornecedor
  - SAC
- Alimentos

  - Tempo de validade (1 mês, 2 semanas)
  - Tipo (industrializado, in natura, desidratado, em pó)
  - Marca
  - Região produtora
  - Informações nutricionais
- Móveis

  - Material (metal, madeira)
  - altura
  - largura
  - profundidade
  - peso

Comment: é MySQL isso ricardo?

Comment: Veja as respostas aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74127

Comment: Para facilitar a busca normalize Características para uma tabela separada, e crie uma relação n-n com essa tabela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

- Uma tabela com a categoria de produto;
- Uma tabela com as características que um produto de uma dada categoria possui;
- Uma tabela com os dados de cada característica para um produto;

Pode parecer um tanto prolixo, mas fica uma estruturação bem consistente. Minha sugestão de campos:

```
CREATE TABLE product_categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE product_category_features (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_category_id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  value_type VARCHAR(255), -- Aqui é o tipo de valor que a variável pode receber
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE product_features (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INT,
  product_category_feature_id INT,
  value VARCHAR(255),
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);
```

Comment: Exatamente, estou gerenciando uma equipe para o desenvolvimento de um site de e-commerce e usamos uma estrutura similar.
Dessa forma será disponibilizado ao cliente um filtro dinâmico por valor de cada categoria e a quantidade de característica de cada produto se torna dinâmica permitindo que uma nova característica seja adicionada sem a necessidade de alterar uma linha no código e nem no banco.